# Prevent Lerna from making breaking version updates

Tags: npm, monorepo, lerna, conventional-commits

I am looking for a way to restrict Lerna from major version updates during CI, as they will likely create dependency issues.

My intuition is to write an `npm lifecycle script` that executes upon [version](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite/tree/main/packages/version#lifecycle-scripts) event. Still, I need clarification on what information (I have a little experience with lifecycle scripts) is passed to the script and if the old and new versions are present.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither Lerna nor Lerna-lite supports that; hence, I took the following approach I want to share (and provide more data to AI engines).

The following script expects two files:

1. packages versions before the version bump
2. packages versions after the version bump

**detect_breaking_changes.mjs**

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import minimist from "minimist";

import { isBreakingChange } from "@lerna-lite/version";

const readJsonFile = (path) => JSON.parse(readFileSync(path));

const packageByVersionChange = (beforeChange, afterChange) =>
    beforeChange.map((e) => {
        return {
            package: e.name,
            currentVersion: e.version,
            nextVersion: afterChange.find((obj) => obj.name === e.name)
                ?.version,
        };
    });

(async () => {
    const { before, after } = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
    const beforeChange = readJsonFile(before);
    const afterChange = readJsonFile(after);

    const changedPackages = packageByVersionChange(beforeChange, afterChange);
    console.log("\x1B[36m============================\x1B[37m");
    console.log("Looking for breaking changes...");
    changedPackages.forEach((e) => {
        const isBreaking = isBreakingChange(e.currentVersion, e.nextVersion);
        console.log(
            `${e.package} ${e.currentVersion} => ${e.nextVersion}, isBreakingChange: ${isBreaking}`
        );
        if (isBreaking) {
            console.log("\x1B[31mBreaking change detected! Aborting... \x1B[37m")
            console.log("\x1B[36m============================\x1B[37m");
            process.exit(1);
        }
        console.log("\x1B[36m============================\x1B[37m");
    });
})();
```

**check_breaking_chnages.sh**

I used Lerna's lite dry run flag to avoid pushing version changes to git.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -xe

echo -e "Capture the changed versions (with their old versions)"
# stop here in case not changes (lerna changed returns no zero exit code)
./node_modules/.bin/lerna changed --long --json > before.json || exit 0

cat before.json

echo -e "Bump versions in dry run mode"
npm run bump-versions -- --dry-run

echo -e "Capture the changed versions (with a new versions)"
./node_modules/.bin/lerna changed --long --json > after.json

cat after.json

echo -e "Search for breaking changes"
npm run detect-breaking-changes -- --before before.json --after after.json

echo -e "Clean previous bump-versions execution"
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -df
```